# WPF Why can I not see submenu during design and which is only partially viewed during runtime?

Tags: menu, submenu

here is my XAML code, It is very simple just for example. I am trying to build this example in VS-2022 and simply trying to understand why the results are counterintuitive. Obviously I am very new to WPF programming.

[ Xaml code]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCkO5.png)

As can be seen I am simply adding a menu bar that has one item Header="File" within that MenuItem I add a submenu Header="New". What I expect to see in the XAML designer window is something like this

[expected XAML Designer window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUyqU.png)

What I see is nothing but the "File" header.
Can anyone explain why I do not see the Header="New" in the designer Window?

I ran the application and the "New" item appears as shown here:

[I run the app and see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e71nw.png)

I would have expected that at least the submenu would have shown inside the application window. I have run into this anomaly on several projects and cannot seem to get a straightforward simple answer to my questions which are two?

Why can I not see the submenu in the designer window during design?
Why does the submenu appear partially outside of the main app window during runtime?

Comment: Ok I think I finally get it. I may be wrong but somewhere alone the way something changed because all over the internet you see tutorials and YouTube videos that show different output windows and designer windows. So I am guessing That "It is what it is." and I will pack up by curious brain and go home. Thanks for listening.

Comment: One additional comment for those  of you that are bothered by this, which apparently is not many. If you really want to see everything like it is in Winforms. Click the Maximize button and click your menu items. Voila!!!